# selenium find elements found wrong location on explorer 11 in c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

c # I am preparing a selenium project. I made a cross browser on the project, but I'm having trouble with internet explorer 11. Locators working correctly in all other browsers also work incorrectly in the intertet explorer.

selenium 3,12
ie version 11.431.16299.00

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QhEsm9cIVNVRi0c37_L3mRc17mbXgR1m

Locator I have used : `By.CssSelector("a.login-button.primary-action");`

HTML :

```
 </nav>
     <nav class="login-navigation active">
          <a href="/teklif-al" class="offer-button secondary-action">Teklif Al</a>
          <nav class="login-menu">
              <a href="#" class="login-button primary-action">Giriş Yap</a>
                  <nav class="login-menu-list">
                            <a href="/yonetici-girisi" class="admin-login-button">Yönetici Girişi</a>
                            <a href="/kullanici-girisi" class="user-login-button">Kullanıcı Girişi</a>
                        </nav>
                    </nav>
                </nav>
```

Comment: provide the relevant HTML for the locator ?

Comment: I added into the question post

Comment: all locators except input locators have the same error

Comment: you are using this locator :  By.CssSelector("a.login-button.primary-action"); , right ?

Comment: You haven't mentioned which element you are trying to click. Perhaps the element with text as `Giriş Yap` contains 2 list items with text as `Yönetici Girişi` and `Kullanıcı Girişi`. Update the question with your _Manual Steps_ you are trying to _Automate_ and your code trials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to official selenium documentation:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

- The browser zoom level must be set to 100% so that the native mouse events can be set to the correct coordinates.
- For Windows 10, you also need to set "Change the size of text, apps, and other items" to 100% in display settings.

Also in "Hovering Elements" section there is a warning:

- When you attempt to hover over elements, and your physical mouse cursor is within the boundaries of the IE browser window, the hover will not work.

If you take into account these configurations, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
Driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Giriş Yap"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
By.CssSelector(".login-button");
         or
By.CssSelector("html body nav.login-navigation.active nav.login-menu a.login-button.primary-action");
```